The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Movie', database 'master', schema 'dbo' (Similar but Different Problem)
This seems to be similar to the problem listed below, but it is different:
The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Users', database 'XXX', schema 'dbo'
The problem is that the user 'dbo' is the database owner (see picture below), as such, I cannot add any other roles in the membership.

So my question is: why am I still denied access to the database and how do I fix it?
Here is the database:


You are showing permissions for database User but the error is in database Master... why are you even adding user tables to Master?

Aside... one could ask why you're even creating application objects in the master database. It's easy enough to backup a master database, but restoring one requires jumping through a number of burning hoops. i.e.: make your life easier and create a user database for your application objects, backup and restore becomes trivial by comparison.

@AlwaysLearning one hopes there is a mistake there... but if not yes indeed!

I didn't add anything. Everything was generated by the system when I installed SQL and added the database to it. Here is the connecting string: Server=luna\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;User Id=\luna\tjfan;TrustServerCertificate=True;Trusted_Connection=True;

I've added a picture to the original post showing the database. Note that even I change the database from 'master' to 'MvcMovieContext-ffba61a8-25a6-4c34-8ce0-2c0283e1a4f3' in the connecting string, I still get the exactly the same message saying database 'master'. So, what IS the fix?

The error message says: "The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Movie', database 'master', schema 'dbo'" no matter what I put into the database in the connecting string. Here is the latest connecting string: Server=luna\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MvcMovieContext-ffba61a8-25a6-4c34-8ce0-2c0283e1a4f3;User Id=\luna\tjfan;TrustServerCertificate=True;Trusted_Connection=True;

After days of trial and error, I finally figured out what was going on.
In summary, it is the database connecting string. Originally, I had my appsettings.json as follows:
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MvcMovieContext": "Server=luna\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MvcMovieContext-ffba61a8-25a6-4c34-8ce0-2c0283e1a4f3;User Id=\\luna\\tjfan;TrustServerCertificate=True;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}

I had another file appsettings.development.json that contains only the first part of the contents as in appsettings.json. I did not have other similar files such as appsettings.production.json.
Everything went well with the database when I ran from within Visual Studio through IIS Express. I dumped the connecting string that was sent to the database and it was exactly the one set in appsettings.json.
However, when I published the project and accessed it through a web browser, the connection was rejected. Further examinations revealed that for whatever reason, the connecting string was reset to access the database 'master'. I searched everywhere in my project and couldn't find anywhere that the connecting string was specifically reset.
After numerous tries, I finally found a solution (which I still don't understand why) by copying appsettings.json into a new file named appsettings.production.json. The contents are exactly the same, and this time the connecting string was set correctly as expected.
Even though the problem got (temporarily) resolved, I'm still confused why this is happening. I thought appsettings.json settings were first applied, and if there was no other similar files such as appsettings.production.json, then the settings would stand. Apparently, something is different here.
Can anyone provide any insight to this?
